# TestNG dependsOnGroups from different class for testng.xml file

Tags: testng

**How to use dependsOnGroups method in testng.xml file so class 1 methods fails class 2 should not run.**

**Class 1:**

```
public class GetDataForChannelAPI{

@Test(dataProvider = "getData", dataProviderClass = DataUtil.class, priority = 2,groups={"getVillagesAndPincodes"})

public void channelAPI_GetPickUpLocation(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) {


//Added some code.

}


}
```

**Class 2:**

```
public class VerifyChannelAPI{

@Test(dataProvider = "getData", dataProviderClass = DataUtil.class, priority = 3, dependsOnGroups = {
            "getVillagesAndPincodes" },groups={"channelAPITest"})

public void channelAPI_Franchise_NoSpace(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) {

//Added some code here
}

}
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Please check below xml code.

```
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getFranchiseIdsGJ" />
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getFranchiseIdsRJ" />
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getFranchiseIdsMH" />
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getOrderIdsGJ" />
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getOrderIdsRJ" />
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getOrderIdsMH" />
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getPackageIdsGJ" />
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getPackageIdsRJ" />
            <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getPackageIdsMH" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.agroex.packageapi.testsuite.VerifyPackageAPI"></class>
        <class name="com.agroex.packageapi.testsuite.GetDataForPackageAPI"></class>
    </classes>

</test> <!-- Test -->
```

Comment: You forgot to format your code and to post your xml file.

Comment: Thanks! i can see the error now, there is a slight confusion between classes and the groups, I'll update the answer and I will explain, bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

Class A:GetDataForPackageAPI

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getData", dataProviderClass = DataUtil.class, priority = 10, groups = {
            "getFranchiseIdsGJ" })
    public void packageAPI_GetFranchiseIdListFor_GJ(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) {
//Some code
}
```

Class B:VerifyPackageAPI

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getData", dataProviderClass = DataUtil.class, priority = 13, dependsOnGroups = {
            "getFranchiseIdsGJ" })
    public void packageAPI_VerifyParameter_FranchiseIdGJ_OpsUser(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) {
        try {
//Add some code
}
```

XML File:

```
<test name="Package API Test" parallel="tests" thread-count="15" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.agroex.packageapi.testsuite.VerifyPackageAPI"></class>
            <class name="com.agroex.packageapi.testsuite.GetDataForPackageAPI"></class>
        </classes>

    </test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see anything wrong in the code you posted; other than it is not formatted :) If the problem is how to construct your xml file:

```
<suite name="PackageAPItest">      

<test name="SmokeTest">

<groups>
<run>
<include name="getVillagesAndPincodes">
</run>
</groups> 

<classes>
<class name="com.agroex.packageapi.testsuite.GetDataForPackageAPI"></class> 
<class name="com.agroex.packageapi.testsuite.VerifyPackageAPI"></class>         
</classes>  

</test>
</suite>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Can you please generate xml which include depends on group.

Comment: Well that's not necessary. You define your group dependencies on your @Test annotation which you have done and then TestNG takes care of it. I'll wait to see your full xml, the error must be there, please upload on your original question below the code.

Comment: <test name="Package API Test" parallel="tests" thread-count="15">       <run>
    <include name="GetDataForPackageAPI.getFranchiseIdsGJ" />    </run>
  </groups>         </test>

Comment: Please check my xml

Comment: If 1st class methods fails testng is allowing and depends on method is running.

Comment: No worries, make the changes and see if you can get it right. If not, post here what happens, and I'll try to help..

Comment: I am sorry if i am not able to communicate my requirement properly,
What i want is - If any of the tests in class A(test suite?) fail, none of the tests in class B should go ahead and execute.

Comment: Correct, you are communicating just fine. So with the above code posted in my main answer, it should work. If any of the test steps (methods) of class #1 (GetDataForChannelAPI) fail then class #2 won't be executed at all. What behaviour are you getting now?

Comment: Wait, I will delete all the extra info, until you solve it and then I'll add it on later stage. For now try to create an xml based on the code I left on the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Xwris Stoixeia. Issue is resolved by using another solution. Please check my answer.

Comment: Can you please try mine as well, and if it works upvote it? I think they are both correct. Thanks! :)

Comment: Xwris Stoixeia : When I include a group in XML that time-dependent method will not throw any exception by testng for e.g class A has groups and class b depends on class A. If class A fails no exception is thrown. Can you please try this.  
Thanks in advance.